# Using FOR or FORFILES batch command to individually archive specific files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, 7zip

I have a set of .iso files in different directories and sub-directories:

```
 <folder1>
    app1.iso
    app2.iso
    app3.iso
    <subfolder1>
        app1a.iso
        app2a.iso
    <subfolder2>
        app2b.iso
        app3b.iso
<folder2>
    app4.iso
    app5.iso
    <subfolder5>
        app20.iso
```

Using a batch file and having 7-zip pre-installed (with PATH environment variable configured), I want to be able to archive each .iso to it's own individual .7z archive file.  I don't want to archive all .iso's in a current folder into one archive.

I attempted to create my own 7-zip command in conjunction with the FORFILES:

```
FORFILES /P . /M *.iso /S /C "cmd /c 7z a -t7z @path.7z -mx9 -mmt >> C:\test\7z-log.txt"
```

However, what this does is:

```
app1.iso.7z - contains: app1.iso, app2.iso, app3.iso
app2.iso.7z - contains: app1.iso.7z, app1.iso, app2.iso, app3.iso
app3.iso.7z - contains: app1.iso.7z, app2.iso.7z, app1.iso, app2.iso, app3.iso
app1a.iso.7z - contains: app1a.iso, app2a.iso
app2a.iso.7z - contains: app1a.iso.7z, app1a.iso, app2a.iso

...
```

What I want is (each in their relevant folder or sub-folder):

```
app1.iso.7z - contains: app1.iso
app2.iso.7z - contains: app2.iso
app3.iso.7z - contains: app3.iso
app1a.iso.7z - contains: app1a.iso
...
```

Can anyone help me on the batch command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s/b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.iso" '
  ) DO (
  ECHO(7z a -t7z "%%~fa.7z" "%%~fa" -mx9 -mmt 
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required 7z commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(7z` to `7z` to actually archive the files.

Note that the redirection-to-log is missing. This is done to allow the proposed actions to be displayed to the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've just got round to trying your example and it works perfectly.  I'm reading more about how to use "delims" so I can break your command down and explain to myself how your answer works.  Many thanks.