# 7zip check seperate folder for changes before compressing

Tags: 7zip

I've got a short script (much if it from online here)..  It zips individual files with 7Zip command line, then I move the file using Robocopy to an archive drive.

What I'm wanting is for the 7Zip to do is look at the archive drive, in the same folder as the file that's about to be zipped for changes.  No changes - don't zip.  Below is the used code from other posts:

Any ideas? 
Thanks,

Bill

```
@ECHO OFF
REM taken from:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633549/using-for-or-forfiles-batch-command-to-individually-archive-specific-files
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=Q:\BackupMirror"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s/b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.*" '
  ) DO (  
    C:\Progra~1\7-Zip\7z.exe a -t7z "%%~fa.7z" "%%~fa" -mx9 -mmt 
    ROBOCOPY Q:\BackupMirror G:\BackupMirrorZips *.7z /e /mov
)
```

Comment: Some suggestions here http://superuser.com/questions/544336/incremental-backup-with-7zip

Comment: Great help!  I'll work on it this week.  Thanks!